# Color Detection in specific object Tensorflow

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection

I am implementing the Tensorflow object detection in on of my android app, I have followed the demo and tutorial of 'Tensorflow-for-poets' and successfully created a model with that.

I need one help with this,
I have this requirement of detecting the traffic signal, I have a dataset and I have created a model for that and in the general case, it works great.

What I want is to detect what color of the traffic signal is lightened, It means is it Green or Red?

I have added dataset which has two types of images of green and red lightened traffic signals but it is just detecting a traffic signal.

Can anyone help me with this or guide how can I achieve this?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977600/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-color-of-a-recognized-object-inside-a-picture?noredirect=1#comment83522734_47977600

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to detect the color of the traffic light?

IMHO it would be more robust to determine which of the lights is shining, e.g. create two classes "red traffic light" and "green traffic light" and train your model on them.

The Answer given in the post referenced in the comments by sladomic is not invariant against noise. Say, you have an Image in the late afernoon, when the sun sets, you likely will have a redish lightened environment. So determing the amount of red pixels within the bounding box of your detected traffic light may will fail, because the amount of red pixels caused by the environmend is larger than the amount of green pixels coming from the flash light.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with that approach at first, But I was not getting proper output, I was getting the green result on red image sometimes, it was getting mixed up.